# Search Console: Server Connectivity Error - Connect Timeout

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, server, crawl-errors

Over the last 4 days server connectivity errors have started to pop up in my Search Console.

[image]

Specifically, it is the connection timeout error.

I have been talking to my hosting provider and they claim there have not and should not be any problems on the server side.

Also, I have reached out for help on the Google Webmaster Forum and there we came up with the following:

- Many requests for images on my own domain (even though cumulative size is large).
- Some images return a 404, though I am aware of this and have a script running that checks if an image gives a 404, and replaces it.  This means there are multiple http requests to image sources that are hosted on my site as well

So, possibly Google bails out sometimes to make sure there is no server overload. Or at least that is what we thought.

If I use "Fetch as Google" it often returns "temporarily unreachable", though sometimes it works.

If I test with Google Pagespeed Insights it also often returns "Timeout while connecting to courseroot.com. Ensure that the page is accessible from the public Internet."

This happens both sometimes for the homepage, but mainly for pages like:

https://courseroot.com/courses/?search=android

I am scared that this issue will affect my rankings.

Comment: This happens from time to time. As long as your site is working there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your response @closetnoc This will not affect my sites performance? I've read in many places that any errors found in these three sections (DNS, Server Connectivity, and Robots.txt) should be taken super seriously. I thought that if Google would think there are errors on a site, it will use this in its ranking mechanism. Would love to hear your thoughts. Thanks again and Merry Christmas.

Comment: No. No worries unless your site is really failing for some reason. Google knows full well that TCP IP is not a guaranteed delivery protocol. Stuff happens! Occasional hiccups won't effect search performance. Merry Christmas to you too!!

Comment: The problem could be on Google's end as opposed to your end.  You should test your site with some other tool, and keep paying attention to that graph, but if you can't reproduce the problem, it may not be anything you can fix.

Comment: On a side note, the fact that Google is crawling `courses/?search=android` at all is problematic.   You should have `Disallow: /courses/?search` in *robots.txt*.   Google doesn't like indexing site search pages.  They see it as poor user experience because users from Google search results click only to find themselves on more search results.  See: [Matt Cutts: Search results in search results](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/).   Google sometimes penalizes entire sites that allow their search results to be crawled and indexed.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Very much appreciated. My site indeed does not give any errors with other testing tools, except Google's. I am going to keep monitoring it and hopefully it will kind of resolve itself. If my rankings start collapsing for no reason, I'll start searching again. Thanks to all, have a good Christmas, and best wishes for the new year. Take care!

Comment: Also worth checking- if your hosting provider or domain registration subscription includes and DDoS services (Cloudflare and Dyn offer this).  If so, you may want to doublecheck that they aren't accidentally throttling and blocking the googlebot.

Answer (score 1):

Added your website to a monitoring service.  Then you will know if the problem is related to your hosting provider.